# How to search posts within specific Labels in blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, search, blogger

I am using Blogger and i want to know how to search posts within specific labels,
for example, i have a bunch of posts labeled as **Marketing**, 
when i search for a specific post by a Query, the WHOLE posts labeled as Marketing shown up instead, as it doesn't do its functions.,

these lines could clarify the issue,

```js
<script type='application/ld+json'>
    //<![CDATA[
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "WebSite",
        "url": "https://mysite.blogspot.com/",
        "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "SearchAction",
            "target": "/search/label/Marketing?q={search_term_string}",
            "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
        }
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

This is the search form i use

```html
<form action='/search/label/Marketing' method='get' itemprop='potentialAction' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/SearchAction'>
  <div>
    <input class='form-control' name='q' placeholder='Search ' type='text' />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be like
`<BLOG_URL>/search?q=label:Marketing+search terms&m=1`